# Silverlight, mouse click on Path with gaps in

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am working on a Silverlight application which displays multiple small icons on a Canvas, each icon being around 10x10 pixels in size. The icon is defined by a Path.

There is a usability issue where some icons are shaped like this, and as a result, if the user clicks in the gap, no click is registered. See the image below to see what I mean.

[image]

I'm wondering, is there an easy way in WPF/Silverlight to enable the "background" of a path to be clickable? Rather than wrapping it in another WPF type which will increase the burden on the renderer.

Alternatively, is there a simple fix to improve the system, say wrap the Path in a Rectangle or other geometry to make the entire area clickable?

Comment: Since you want to avoid nesting it in another type, maybe try having a path also fill in those gaps with a transparent colour path?

Comment: Would you know how to do that? As far as I'm aware Path supports fill, stroke but not multiple colours. Or do you mean two paths?

Comment: That would require putting a plain rectangle path behind the actual path and handling the same click events. That might even be worse overhead than a rectangle, but you'd need to time test. Definitely harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a drawing brush with a drawing group, instead of a path.

```
<Rectangle Name="TransparentBack"  Height="10" Width="10">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <Rect Height="1" Width="1"/>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="White">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <LineSegment Point="0,1"/>
                                    <LineSegment Point="1,1"/>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: BTW, the transparent geometry isn't in fact needed. I like direct control over the rendering area.